# Requirements.txt - как получить?

Tags: python, django

Как получить requirements.txt, имея django проект?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

С помощью команды:

```
pip freeze
```

Comment: Это если проект работает. Если нет  - запускать, смотреть, на какие библиотеки ругается, и гуглить эти библиотеки.

Comment: спасибо, создание удалось

Comment: Чтобы получить запрошенный файл потребуется перенаправить вывод этой команды в файл: **pip freeze > requirements.txt**

Comment: Не забывайте только, что это список **всех** пакетов, имеющихся в текущем интерпретаторе, а не только использующихся в проекте

Answer (score 26):

Чтобы получить список пакетов в проекте выполняем команду

```
pip freeze
```

Для записи вывода в requirements.txt дополняем следующим образом:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Команду выполняем в корне проекта. Там же появится и файл. Подразумевается использование активного venv для текущего проекта. При выполнении вне виртуальной среды текущего проекта могут быть подтянуты лишние пакеты, не связанные с текущим проектом!

Comment: Добавьте комментарии к своему ответу. Что происходит в этом куске кода, чем это может помочь и т.п.

Comment: Это список **всех** пакетов, имеющихся в текущем интерпретаторе, а не только использующихся в проекте

Comment: Подразумевается использование venv, который для каждого проекта свой.

Comment: `При выполнении вне виртуальной среды текущего проекта могут быть подтянуты лишние пакеты` - это не совсем так. Будут подтянуты пакеты из _текущей_ виртуальной среды. Так в общем случае эта среда никак не связана с проектом, то там может быть все что угодно, т.е. не просто _лишние_, а вообще другие - установленные в тут другую виртуальную среду.

Answer (score 10):

Лучше всего смотреть в INSTALLED_APPS и выковыривать всё вручную. С `pip freeze` есть вариант получить тыкву через некоторое время, ибо он вытягивает абсолютно все пакеты вместе с их зависимостями (включая системные), а пакеты со временем обновляются, старые версии удаляются. Да и нечего вам рулить зависимостями вручную - это задача менеджера пакетов (pip или easy_install).

Лучше всего заполнять файл requirements по мере написания проекта, а не после.

Добавлено: Есть подходящая опция у pip: `pip freeze --local`.

Из справки: If in a virtualenv that has global access, do not output globally-installed packages.

Answer (score 5):

Чтобы создать `requirements.txt` или обновить уже существующий файл, чтобы он соответствовал текущему virtualenv, можно использовать [`pip-dump` команду](https://github.com/nvie/pip-tools):

```
$ pip install pip-tools
$ pip-dump
```

[Пакет работает на *nix системах](https://github.com/nvie/pip-tools/issues/121).

Answer (score 2):

Для работы с *requirements.txt* есть Python библиотека `pipreqs`

Установка: `pip install pipreqs`

- Чтобы сгенерировать файл *requirements.txt* используйте `pipreqs /path/to/project/folder`
- Если *requirements.txt* уже есть и необходимо его перезаписать, то используйте флаг `—force`
- Если нужно просто посмотреть на используемые библиотеки без создания, флаг `—print`

Подробнее [здесь](http://zabaykin.ru/?p=436)

Answer (score 2):

Если вы работаете в PyCharm, то можно сформировать requirements.txt на основе текущего проекта: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/managing-dependencies.html. Удобно, так как добавляются только пакеты которые используются в проекте.
Может быть аналогичный инструмент в другой используемой IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Чет сначала прочел по-русски а отвечать начал по-английски. Ну так вот, немного магии если нет venv

If you have little project THIS will do some magic

`` for i in `cat *.py | grep -R import | sort |  uniq | sed 's/^import//; s/^from//; s/ import.*//'`; do python -m pip freeze --local | grep -i $i; done ``

You should check it, but it work.
Проходит по всем файлам, собирает импорты и грепает по установленным пакетам, естественно не ищет полное соответствие, поэтому будут лишние, но не много.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, переведите текст ответа, нажав [edit]